# Cut/paste source code of a picture makes the picture corrupt

Tags: windows-10, compression, encoding, pictures

I have tried the following only in windows 10, I'm using the default apps.

If I open a movie file in a text editor, I cut some of it, place it some other place, then paste it back in, the movie would play just fine. Same applies for pretty much anything except pictures.

If I do the same with a png, it doesn't work. Is it the picture that is getting corrupted by the process or it is windows' fault for not being able to open the file. What amazes me is that I'm just having the problem with images.

Comment: @Ramhound, if too broad is the reason, then U could remove the compression/encoding part. If the first part is answered then I would know the answer to the second part

Comment: @DavidPostill please read the comment above

Comment: The subject matter is quite broad- perhaps you could clarify why you would expect cutting and pasting "*some parts*" of an image to work, and what you would expect to happen?

Comment: You probably also have that problem with a movie just in comparison the amount of data that get corrupted is minor.

Comment: @Seth then my question is, how do file achievers handle encoding after decompression? Since detecting file encoding beforehand is tricky and doesn't always work

Comment: Which is pretty much a completely different question? In addition it's not hard to detect the encoding because you implement a certain spec and magic numbers/[file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) help you to identify what kind of format a file should be. As for archive file managers ... they don't handle encoding because they just decompress the files (in most cases).

Comment: @Seth it seems like a different question, I had to omit that part because my question was labeled "too broad" but it's really the essence of it. I stumbled upon the problem above while testing compression algorithms for a project I'm working on, I wanted to know how to detect file encoding in c++ and got results like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523217/detect-encoding-of-a-string-in-c-c which is guessing. So I did the tests listed in the question above by hand to see what would happen

Comment: Which is yet again a different question because it's not about compression or file format/file encoding detection but rather text encoding which has its own problems thanks to code pages and extended ASCII. Which is also, in part, the reason why editing binary files like PNGs and movies with a text editor is such a bad idea. By copying the text you copy it into the clipboard ([which also has a format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx)) and by pasting it back it might actually be modified.